# Can't access attributes from XML response using simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, simplexml, cxml

I'm trying to use simplexml_load_string to get the Status and Text values from the following XML response;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>    
<cXML payloadID="online" xml:lang="en" timestamp="2017-12-04T15:57:47.6693296+00:00">
  <Response>
    <Status code="402" text="&#x9;&#xA; product 325552not in customer[20690]  pricelist" />
  </Response>
</cXML>
```

In my PHP code I am getting the XML above from $reply:

```
$reply = curl_exec($curl);
```

I am then using simplexml_load_string like so:

```
$responseData = simplexml_load_string($reply);
echo 'Sync Order - '. $order->getIncrementId() . ' Status '. $responseData->Response->Status['code'] .' - '. $responseData->Response->Status['text'];
```

But this doesn't seem to get the code and text from the XML response above. Wondering if anyone has any ideas to help?

Thank you.

Note: The cXML is correct.

Comment: Just tried your code with the XML listed and I get `Status 402 - product 325552not in customer[20690]  pricelist` (omitting order bit)

Comment: @NigelRen Strange - i'm wondering if it's due to the utf-16 encoding why I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried it with the added xml header and UTF-16 encoding bit and it fails to load with an error...

> PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error :
>   Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content in

A simple but crude way round it is to change the UTF in the xml element to UTF8...

```
$reply = preg_replace('/(<\?xml[^?]+?)utf-16/i', '$1utf-8', $reply);
$responseData = simplexml_load_string($reply);
```

This then gives the output as expected...

```
 Status 402 -   
 product 325552not in customer[20690]  pricelist
```